# Getting data from IList inside child ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to iterate over a collection of child objects from my parent controller.

```
 public class ListBlogsPageModel : IPageViewModel<ListBlogsPage>
 {
     public IList<BlogPage> BlogPages { get; set; }
 }
```

BlogPages contain an index of BlogPage. This BlogPage model contains an IList of ProfilePage I want to iterate over in my parent controller.

```
public class BlogPageModel : IPageViewModel<BlogPage>
{
    public IList<ProfilePage> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

Now my question is how do I access this child Profiles model in the parent ListBlogsPage? I have tried getting Profiles the same way I am already getting BlogPage children (see below) but I seems to receive no values.

```
public ActionResult Index(ListBlogsPage currentPage)
{
    var model = new ListBlogsPageModel(currentPage);
    var blogPages = _contentLoader.GetChildren<BlogPage>(currentPage.ContentLink).ToList();
    var authorPages = _contentLoader.GetChildren<ProfilePage>(currentPage.ContentLink).ToList();
    var filteredPages = _contentFilterService.FilterForDisplay(blogPages, false, true).ToList();
    var filteredAuthors = _contentFilterService.FilterForDisplay(authorPages, false, true).ToList();
    model.BlogPages = filteredPages;
    model.AuthorPages = filteredAuthors;
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (page in model.BlogPages)
{
    page.Profiles = something;
}
```

I could be wrong, but it seems like you asked this.

Comment: Thanks! is this code meant for the Index controller? or is it to render a view with profiles?

Comment: It can be used anywhere, but in this case for the controller.